# SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship deletion operation on one side

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship linked by an association table, like this:

```
left_right_association_table = Table("left_right_association_table", Base.metadata,
        Column('leftside_id', Integer, ForeignKey('leftside_table.id')),
        Column('rightside_id', Integer, ForeignKey('rightside_table.id'))
    )

class LeftSide(Base):
    ...
    rightside_members = relationship("RightSide", secondary=left_right_association_table, backref="leftside", lazy="joined")
    ...


class RightSide(Base):
    ...
```

Now I have a `LeftSide` instance, with a `list` of `RightSide` instances as its `rightside_members` attribute:

```
ls = LeftSide(**kw)
rs1 = RightSide(**kw)
rs2 = RightSide(**kw)
ls.rightside_members.append(rs1)
ls.rightside_members.append(rs2)
```

Then, I want to drop one of the list member: `rs2`.

Step 1: I reproduce the `rightside_members` list:

```
updated_rightside_members = [RightSide(**rs_attrs) for rs_attrs in ls.rightside_members] # each `rs` object already has primary key
updated_rightside_members.pop() # remove the second item from the list
```

Step 2: I retrieve the `ls` from the database:

```
old_ls = db_session.query(LeftSide).filter(LeftSide_id == ls.id).one()
```

Step 3: I tack the updated_rightside_members onto the `old_ls`:

```
old_ls.rightside_members = updated_rightside_members
```

Step 4: commit to database.

```
db_session.commit()
```

Then I get this Error:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rightside_table.id
```

It seems to me that SQLAlchemy is thinking that I'm trying to put a duplicate `rs1` back into the database, instead of deleting its brother `rs2` from the database.

How should I do this deletion operation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are removing the item from the relationship. FWIW, [this code](https://pastebin.com/qReeNjJt) works fine for me.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes you are absolutely right. I just edited my steps.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem. First I really want to point out that reading carefully the documentation helps. Using mapped class to initialize an instance doesn't mean the session knows about this object, at least not until you use `Session.add()` method.

So, the proper steps should be like this:

1. decide whether the incoming args contain a `id` which represent the instance primary key. If it does, then instead of initialize it, the right way to do is to query it from the database. This way the `Session` will ensure that the queried object has a unique object id in its `identity map`.
2. if it doesn't contain an `id` attribute, then initialize it, and add it to the member list.

Comment: Yes. Essentially you were creating new RightSide objects (via `RightSide(**rs_attrs)`) instead of operating on the existing RightSide objects that the session knew about. My sample code worked because I was operating on the list of existing RightSide objects so the session was able to keep track of them.